# How do I configure prerender.io to work on webapp2 for my angularjs app?

Tags: angularjs, webapp2, google-app-engine-python, prerender

I have been trying to configure the prerender.io middleware for my angularjs app hosted on google app engine with webapp2 framework, but none of the options for installing the middleware token seem applicable.

Can anyone be kind enough to assist me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If Google doesn't allow you to modify the server to install one of the middleware options, are you using a CDN? A CDN might allow you to set up the Prerender.io middleware on their platform. Feel free to email us at support@prerender.io